# A cleaner way of appending the same image element to all of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that displays links to news articles as squares, with a **background image** stretching the full height and width, and with an overlay containing text at the bottom.

[image]

I need an image (a view icon) to appear when hovering over the parent div. This needs to happen on every single news link element (there will be a lot).

### Solution #1

I can use CSS to achieve this, but as far as I can tell, I would need to add the image as an `img` element to every single div that needs it. Due to this feeling like a waste of time, I looked for another approach.

### Solution #2

Using JavaScript and JQuery, I can create an `img` element upon hovering over the news link, and the append to the news link. This means that I can position it using css, and just add the class using JQuery.

```js
$('.slides .image-container').on('mouseover', function(){
  if ($('.view-symbol').length === 0) {
    var img = $(document.createElement('img')); 
    img
      .attr('src', 'images/view.png')
      .addClass('view-symbol');
    $(this).append(img);
  }
});
```

This should check whether the image is already being displayed or not. If not then it will create it.

```js
$('.slides .image-container').on('mouseout', function(){
  if ($('.view-symbol').is(':hover')) {
    $('.view-symbol').show();
  }
  $('.view-symbol').on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
  });
  $('.view-symbol').hide(0, function(){
    $('.view-symbol').remove(); 
  });
});
```

This then hides it upon the `mouseout` event occurring over the div.

### The problem with this apporach

Using this method, when the mouse hovers over the image itself, it detects the mouse having left the parent div of the news link, and therefore removes the element. Once it has been removed, the mouse is hovering over the news element again and the image returns. This creates a flickering.

### The question

Is there a way to amend my code, or a different approach I can be pointed towards for solving this problem?

### #Edit

Here is the output html for the links

```html
<div class='small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns'>
  <div id='news-left'>
    <div class='image-container'>
      <img src='images/news1.jpg'>
        <div class='news-overlay'>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quis est, qui non oderit libidinosam
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why over complicate things with jquery, what is the html output for the links created? can you supply that please

Comment: The answer would be to use simple css to achieve this affect, no jquer needed.

Comment: Have you looked into background-image? You could just trigger the background image of an arbitrary element, which is in front of the news.

Comment: You could use the `:after` pseudo element, and combine it with `:hover`, that way you don't have to change any of your existing markup  - http://jsfiddle.net/ypj1b94h/

Comment: That's brilliant Nick, almost exactly what I am after. I can modify that to work perfectly for me. If you want to put as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have a CSS class with a `background-image` set and then use JavaScript to add or remove the class when hovering.

Or alternatively, use the `:hover` psuedo class and have that with a background image.

So perhaps something like this:

**JQuery**

```
$('.slides .image-container').hover( function() {
    $(this).addClass('viewImage');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('viewImage');
})
```

**CSS**

```
.viewImage {    
    background: url('my_view_image.png');
}
```

Or just

**CSS**

```
.myDiv:hover {
    background: url('my_view_image.png');
}
```

Both of these are similar to your second solution, which is the right way to go.

Regarding the 'flickering' you describe, it's hard to tell precisely, but I'd imagine this is because you're creating html elements each time and showing them, creating a new one each time which may take a little while.

You should be creating a class with a background image and applying that (no html creation) or alternative creating your element once and appending / removing it from the parent you want it to apply to. Creating an element on each hover is too time consuming, which is what I'd guess your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

with css using `:hover` and `:before` with bakground image. Something like this:

```css
.something{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  outline:2px solid black;
  margin:40px 20px;
  position:relative;
}
/* this one added */
.something:hover:after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  left:0;
  bottom:100%;
}
.something:hover:before{
  position:absolute;
  left:15px;
  top:-30px;
  content:"";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:/* url(yourImage) */ red;
}
```

```html
<div class="something">1</div>
<div class="something">2</div>
<div class="something">3</div>
<div class="something">4</div>
<div class="something">5</div>
```

**edit** as soon as you have "touching" div and `:before`/`:after` element, it will not disapear. NOTE: you dont need 2 of them, just use right background positioning for your image

Comment: This is very close, but is it possible to avoid flickering if the red circle is moved within the container, and you hover over it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code
**HTML**

```
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".square").mouseover(function() {
        $(".addImage").removeClass("addImage");
       $(this).addClass("addImage"); 
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.addImage {
    background-image: url("myimage.png");
}
```